# Get only numbers fron expo contacts

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am gettings contacts from expo contacts using

```
  const { status } = await Contacts.requestPermissionsAsync();
      if (status === "granted") {
        const { data } = await Contacts.getContactsAsync({
          fields: [Contacts.Fields.PhoneNumbers],
          pageSize: 5,
          pageOffset: 0,
          
        });
        if (data.length > 0) {
         //   console.log(JSON.stringify(data[0].phoneNumbers))
         
      console.log(data)
}
```

the response looks like this

```
Array [
  Object {
    "company": "Daniel",
    "contactType": "company",
    "id": "2898",
    "imageAvailable": false,
    "lookupKey": "3512i1529c72c8cc50cd4",
    "name": "Danieltoby_Official",
    "phoneNumbers": Array [
      Object {
        "id": "6616",
        "isPrimary": 0,
        "label": "mobile",
        "number": "+234819000738",
        "type": "2",
      },
    ],
  },
 
  Object {
    "contactType": "person",
    "firstName": "john",
    "id": "13122",
    "imageAvailable": false,
    "lookupKey": "3512i168d77140cbb4b33",
    "name": "0cc",
    "phoneNumbers": Array [
      Object {
        "id": "28940",
        "isPrimary": 0,
        "label": "unknown",
        "number": "080093952483",
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

I just want to get the numbers and check it against numbers in my database to return only contacts of registered users.

I have tried all bunch of thing but didn't work. How can I get only the list of number value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).

```js
const numbers = data
// returns a array of `.phoneNumbers` property.
.map(contact => contact.phoneNumbers)
// creates a new array with all sub-array elements concatenated into it recursively
.flat()

console.log(numbers)

/*
[
  {
    "id": "6616",
    "isPrimary": 0,
    "label": "mobile",
    "number": "+234819000738",
    "type": "2"
  },
  {
    "id": "28940",
    "isPrimary": 0,
    "label": "unknown",
    "number": "080093952483"
  },
]

*/


// you can still use `.map` through `numbers` to return array of numbers<strings>

const numbersArray = numbers.map(n => n.number);
```

Comment: This seemed to work better in getting the number and to remove returned undefined results in my case  ````numbers.forEach(function(item, index){ if(item !== undefined){console.log(item.number) } })````

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
const { status } = await Contacts.requestPermissionsAsync();
      if (status === "granted") {
        const { data } = await Contacts.getContactsAsync({
          fields: [Contacts.Fields.PhoneNumbers],
          pageSize: 5,
          pageOffset: 0,
          
        });
        let phoneNumbers = [];
        if (data.length > 0) {
          for (let i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
             phoneNumbers.push(data[i].phoneNumbers[0].number);
          }
        
       // all the phone numbers will be in phoneNumbers variable
}
```